# What's the difference between connecting signals and slot in code and setting them in QtCreator "Signals and Slots Editor" window?

Tags: qt

What's the difference between connecting signals and slot in your c++ code and setting them in QtCreator "Signals and Slots Editor" window?

I saw in QtCreator window, there is also a "Signals and Slots Editor" widget and "Action editor" widget so that I can add  and edit. But when should I use it? Or I can just neglect it? Please tell me what is the best rule to follow. Thanks

Comment: I use both. I mean I try to do as much of the connections for a .ui file that I can in the designer however when I am connecting to external classes it is usually easier to type in my c++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the difference between connecting signals and slot in your c++
>   code and setting them in QtCreator "Signals and Slots Editor" window?

Nothing.  When you use the editor, it writes the data into your `.ui` file, which is then used to create the C++ code using the `uic` preprocessor.

> there is also a "Signals and Slots Editor" widget and "Action editor"
>   widget so that I can add and edit. But when should I use it? Or I can
>   just neglect it? Please tell me what is the best rule to follow.

There is no 'rule to follow', it is personal taste.  I *personally* find the Designer a blunt tool to use, so other than dialogs, I rarely use it; whilst others find it great aid and do as much as possible using it.

Comment: Hmm, one more question, are you saying actually one can design the whole qt graphic interface by source code alone without even using the help of qt designer?

Comment: Of course!  The designer creates XML (the `ui` file) which is parsed by the `uic` which creates C++ code, so there's nothing stopping you (in fact is quite _normal_) to write everything by hand.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in the functionality. You can use whatever suits you better. However, I would suggest to be consistent and try to stick to one method whenever possible. This makes it easier to find which connections are made - especially if the code is to be maintained by some other people.

If you often connect signals to non-visual objects, you may find it easier to keep all connections in the source code, but your mileage may very.